# Unmet dependency for mono-devel stops me from installing any package

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I'm trying to install ncurses on my Ubuntu. I keep getting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Le paquet « mono-roslyn » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Vous pouvez lancer « apt-get -f install » pour corriger ces problèmes :
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 mono-devel : Dépend: mono-roslyn (= 5.4.1.7-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1) mais ne sera pas installé
              Dépend: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.4.1.7-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1) mais 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+ubuntu1604b1 devra être installé
E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt-get -f install » sans paquet
(ou indiquez une solution).
```

I've already tried to update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, remove, clean, apt-get install -f, ....

What else can I try?

I've already followed this post:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa?newreg=d346b323cef7470cb33bc8f32c7387e7)

Comment: Those are Mono package errors, not ncurses errors. Whatever non-Ubuntu source you chose to install Mono from, uninstall ALL packages from that source. Those mono packages seem incompatible with your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please explain it a little bit? Mono is an Windows emulator, so what it is do here?

Comment: For the explanation, read the error messages you posted. It doesn't matter what you are tyring to install *now*, any apt actions will result in the same mono package errors. Mono *package* errors, not mono *runtime* errors.  Did you install Mono from some non-Ubuntu source?

Comment: No that's why I don't understand why it is here...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and the complete contents of all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Also try uninstalling those three mono-related packages using apt - if any errors, post that session, too.

Comment: Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy mono-devel mono-roslyn ca-certificates-mono`. Please note that `mono-roslyn` package is not part of official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Your question is unclear and it appears to be abandoned, but restoring the default repositories would be a logical step under these circumstances. Please reply to the questions asked in the comments and comment to me if you want this question to be reopened.